# Array of non-serializable objects is serilzable?

Tags: java, android, serialization

To the best of my knowledge "com.google.api.services.drive.model.File" is not serilizable.  When I look it up [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html) it doesn't implement serilizable, and when I try to put it to an intent as a serilizable (as shown below) I get a compiler error preventing me.

Yet if I wrap these non-serilizable files into an array, I get no compiler warning when I write it to an intent as a serilizable.  I thought it must surely result in a run time error though -- perhaps the compiler just cant see I'm holding non-serilizable objects in the array.

Curiosity got the better of me and I ran the test, and to my surprise it worked.  I successfully broadcast with an intent my array of files to component parts, and retrieved data from them.

So can someone explain to me why this working as it is?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String key = "key";

    //com.google.api.services.drive.model.File is not serializable (I think)
    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = new File();
    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File[] files = new File[]{};

    intent.putExtra(key, files);  // yet serializing array of files, no compiler error
    intent.putExtra(key, file);   // putting just one file, compiler error.
```

Edit: I understand that wrapping the un-serialized file is making java inspect it as a serializable, but what happens if the class has private fields?  Actually File does have private fields (albeit with lots of public get/sets)..., how is serialize recording the private fields -- isn't it suppose to be withheld?  In other words, is there risk of data loss from some fields being private, or is the class just handing everything over to the serialization process now?

Answer (score -1):

Serializable is just a marker interface to tell the compiler that you want your object to be able to be serialized. Since arrays are Serializable, their contents will be serialized.